# fullpage and two-column figure in latex

Tags: texmaker

I need to insert 3 images. one of them take one whole page and not be centered on one of the columns and another two images stand side by side in two column.So they will look like:
[image]

I used this codes for the first image but it completely destroys my layout from two-column to one-column document

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
‎\onecolumn\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Soft-PCAAlpha08}‎
\caption{caption}
\end{figure*}
```

I would really appreciate if you guys can provide any help.

Comment: remove `\onecolumn` from `figure*` float environment. it is superfluous and make your problems.

Comment: @Zarko thank you it works fine now. but how can I add another two images below on the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but if you want a single caption

```
\begin{figure*}% don't omit p![ht]
\centering
‎\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Soft-PCAAlpha08}‎

‎\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Soft-PCAAlpha08-a}‎
‎\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Soft-PCAAlpha08-b}‎

\caption{caption}
\end{figure*}
```

or three captions

```
\begin{figure*}% don't omit p![ht]
\centering
‎\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Soft-PCAAlpha08}‎

\caption{caption}

‎\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}[t]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Soft-PCAAlpha08-a}‎
\caption{caption a}
\end{minipage}%
‎\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}[t]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Soft-PCAAlpha08-b}‎
\caption{caption b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```